# How to make a button in xcode send a url to webview

Tags: xcode, macos, webview

I have a window with buttons along the top, then under that a webview to display a locally hosted web application.

Using the buttons on the top of the window I would like to for example click home and this updates the url to localhost/home.

I have built what I want easily in visual studio for the windows version, however I am new to apple products and can't seem to find a way to store a string in the button and send that to the webview.

Another thing that I would like is the option to set a url for the web view on load.

I have searched however it give code examples, I can't find in xcode where it generates the code for the buttons, I found the xml via viewing the source but that didn't seem to help.

Thanks

Comment: Post some code of what you've got so far.

Comment: @PeterFoti Where about is that? I have been building it in interface mode and then running it, but as I said before none of the c# code seems to be getting bigger only the XML.

Comment: Im asking what Objective-C and/or Swift code you've written thus far that you're asking about.